# Android game crashes FATAL EXCEPTION main

Tags: java, android

My app has 2 activities a main menu and a game play activity. you click play to start the game play and when you die you can click back to go to the main menu. For some reason when i click play for the third time (meaning ive died and went back to the main menu twice) the game crashes with this error.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.example.jordanschanzenbach.myapplication, PID: 1875
          java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 360012 byte allocation with 79976 free bytes and 78KB until OOM
          at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
          at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
          at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:700)
          at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:535)
          at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:558)
          at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:588)
          at com.example.jordanschanzenbach.myapplication.Obstacle.<init>(Obstacle.java:44)
          at com.example.jordanschanzenbach.myapplication.ObstacleManager.populateObstacles(ObstacleManager.java:57)
          at com.example.jordanschanzenbach.myapplication.ObstacleManager.<init>(ObstacleManager.java:38)
          at com.example.jordanschanzenbach.myapplication.GamePlayScene.<init>(GamePlayScene.java:41)
          at com.example.jordanschanzenbach.myapplication.GamePanel.<init>(GamePanel.java:29)
          at com.example.jordanschanzenbach.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
```

that's not the entire error message but i think i gave you what you needed. Now i tried to make an animation for the obstacles to be spikes instead of just black rectangles but for some reason the spikes will not display and i think it might correspond with the error i receive. But i don't understand why the spikes wont display as i used the same code for the animation for my player.

here is the code for my obstacle

```
public class Obstacle implements GameObject
{

private Rect rectangle;
private Rect rectangle2;
private int color;

private Animation falling;
private Animation fallingStill;
private Animation fallingAgain;
private AnimationManagerObstacle animationManagerObstacle;

public Rect getRectangle()
{
    return rectangle;
}

public void IncrementY(float y )
{
    rectangle.top += y;
    rectangle.bottom += y;
    rectangle2.top += y;
    rectangle2.bottom += y;
}

public Obstacle(int rectHeight, int color, int startX, int startY, int playerGap)
{
    this.color = color;

    BitmapFactory bitfac = new BitmapFactory();
    Bitmap fallings = bitfac.decodeResource(GlobalVariables.CURRENT_CONTEXT.getResources(), R.drawable.spikesupsidedown);
    Bitmap fallingStills = bitfac.decodeResource(GlobalVariables.CURRENT_CONTEXT.getResources(), R.drawable.spikesupsidedown);
    Bitmap fallingAgains = bitfac.decodeResource(GlobalVariables.CURRENT_CONTEXT.getResources(), R.drawable.spikesupsidedown);

    falling = new Animation(new Bitmap[]{fallings}, 2);
    fallingStill = new Animation(new Bitmap[]{fallings, fallingStills}, 0.5f);
    fallingAgain = new Animation(new Bitmap[]{fallings, fallingAgains}, 0.5f);

    animationManagerObstacle = new AnimationManagerObstacle(new Animation[]{falling, fallingStill, fallingAgain});

    rectangle = new Rect(0, startY, startX, startY + rectHeight);
    rectangle2 = new Rect(startX + playerGap, startY, GlobalVariables.SCREEN_WIDTH, startY + rectHeight);
}

public boolean playerCollide(RectPlayer player)
{
    return Rect.intersects(rectangle, player.getRectangle()) || Rect.intersects(rectangle2, player.getRectangle());

}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas)
{
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(color);

    animationManagerObstacle.draw(canvas, rectangle);

    canvas.drawRect(rectangle, paint);
    canvas.drawRect(rectangle2, paint);
}

@Override
public void update()
{
    animationManagerObstacle.update();
}

public void update(Point point)
{
    float oldTop = rectangle.top;

    rectangle.set(point.x - rectangle.width() / 2,
            point.y - rectangle.height() / 2,
            point.x + rectangle.width() / 2,
            point.y + rectangle.height() / 2);

    int state = 0;
    if (rectangle.left - oldTop > 1)
    {
        state = 1;
    }
    else if (rectangle.left - oldTop < 2)
    {
        state = 2;
    }

    animationManagerObstacle.playAnim(state);
    animationManagerObstacle.update();

}

}
```

this is the line that the error message points to

```
Bitmap fallings = bitfac.decodeResource(GlobalVariables.CURRENT_CONTEXT.getResources(), R.drawable.spikesupsidedown);
```

here is my obstacle manager where i add and display the obstacles

```
public class ObstacleManager
{

private ArrayList<Obstacle> obstacles;
private int playerGap;
private int obstacleGap;
private int obstacleHeight;
private int color;

private long startTime;
private long initTime;

private int score = 0;

public ObstacleManager(int playerGap, int obstacleGap, int obstacleHeight, int color)
{
    this.playerGap = playerGap;
    this.obstacleGap = obstacleGap;
    this.obstacleHeight = obstacleHeight;
    this.color = color;

    startTime = initTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    obstacles = new ArrayList<>();

    populateObstacles();
}

public boolean playerCollide(RectPlayer player)
{
    for(Obstacle ob : obstacles)
    {
        if(ob.playerCollide(player))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private void populateObstacles()
{
    int currY = -5 * GlobalVariables.SCREEN_HEIGHT / 4;
    while(currY < 0)
    {
        int xStart = (int)(Math.random()*(GlobalVariables.SCREEN_WIDTH - playerGap));
        obstacles.add(new Obstacle(obstacleHeight, color, xStart, currY, playerGap));
        currY += obstacleHeight + obstacleGap;
    }
}

public void update()
{
    if (GlobalVariables.GAMEOVER)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            obstacles.remove(obstacles.size() - 2);
        }
    }

    int elapsedTime = (int)(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    float speed = (float)(Math.sqrt((1 + startTime - initTime) / 1750.0)) * GlobalVariables.SCREEN_HEIGHT /17500.0f;
    for(Obstacle ob : obstacles)
    {
        ob.IncrementY(speed * elapsedTime);
    }
    if(obstacles.get(obstacles.size() - 1).getRectangle().top >= GlobalVariables.SCREEN_HEIGHT * 3/4)
    {
        int xStart = (int)(Math.random()*(GlobalVariables.SCREEN_WIDTH - playerGap));
        obstacles.add(0, new Obstacle(obstacleHeight, color, xStart,
                obstacles.get(0).getRectangle().top - obstacleHeight - obstacleGap, playerGap));
        obstacles.remove(obstacles.size() - 1);
        score++;

        if (score > GlobalVariables.HIGHSCORE)
            GlobalVariables.HIGHSCORE = score;
    }
}

public void draw(Canvas canvas)
{
    for(Obstacle ob : obstacles)
        ob.draw(canvas);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setTextSize(100);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    canvas.drawText("" + score, 50, 50 + paint.descent() - paint.ascent(), paint);
    canvas.drawText("HighScore: " + GlobalVariables.HIGHSCORE, GlobalVariables.SCREEN_WIDTH  / 2 + 50, 50 + paint.descent() - paint.ascent(), paint);
}
}
```

here is my animation manager

```
public class AnimationManager
{
private Animation[] animations;
private int animationsIndex = 0;

public AnimationManager(Animation[] animations)
{
    this.animations = animations;
}

public void playAnim(int index)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < animations.length; i++)
    {
        if (i == index)
        {
            if (!animations[index].isPlaying())
            {
                animations[i].play();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            animations[i].stop();
        }
    }
    animationsIndex = index;
}

public void draw(Canvas canvas, Rect rect)
{
    if (animations[animationsIndex].isPlaying())
    {
        animations[animationsIndex].draw(canvas, rect);
    }
}

public void update()
{
    if (animations[animationsIndex].isPlaying())
    {
        animations[animationsIndex].update();
    }
}
}
```

and finally my animation class

```
public class Animation
{
private Bitmap[] frames;
private int frameIndex;

private boolean isPlaying = false;
public boolean isPlaying()
{
    return isPlaying;
}

public void play()
{
    isPlaying = true;
    frameIndex = 0;
    lastFrame = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

public void stop()
{
    isPlaying = false;
}

private float frameTime;
private long lastFrame;

public Animation(Bitmap[] frames, float animTime)
{
    this.frames = frames;
    frameIndex = 0;

    frameTime = animTime / frames.length;

    lastFrame = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

public void draw(Canvas canvas, Rect destination)
{
    if (!isPlaying)
        return;

    scaleRect(destination);

    canvas.drawBitmap(frames[frameIndex], null, destination, new Paint());
}

private void scaleRect(Rect rect)
{
    float whRatio = (float)(frames[frameIndex].getWidth() / frames[frameIndex].getHeight());

    if (rect.width() > rect.height())
    {
        rect.left = rect.right - (int)(rect.height() * whRatio);
    }
    else
    {
        rect.top = rect.bottom - (int)(rect.width() * (1 / whRatio));
    }
}

public void update()
{
    if (!isPlaying)
        return;

    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastFrame > frameTime * 1000)
    {
        frameIndex++;

        if (frameIndex >= frames.length)
            frameIndex = 0;

        lastFrame = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
}
```

i dont think you necessarily needed all that but just in case :). thanks for any comments to improve or help.

Comment: I also experience this kind of error main reason for this is that you have a big file just by reading at the first line of error (OUTOFMEMORY) you may want to edit your file to have a smaller byte size

Comment: how would you recommend that i cut down on the byte size? is there a way that i can clear old threads or clear what is being stored each time i change activities?

Comment: in my past encounter I have an ImageView that shows the image then I cut down the width and height of that image to a smaller width and height so that the byte size be lessen

Comment: What about using a game engine? This is the sort of think that you don't want to have to manager by hand and an engine will help significantly.

Comment: ok thank you. on a side note do you have any idea why my obstacles wont display as my animation and are just rectangles?

Comment: shmuel, i'm very to new to making apps or games on android so implementing a game engine is something i have no clue how to do.

Comment: i have my own while loop running the game as of now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OutOfMemoryError` basically means that you tried to use more memory than you can. In this specific example you (bitmap) tried to allocate 360KB though you could only allocate 78KB more. You might have a memory leak somewhere or your bitmap might be too big. I think your Bitmaps might be leaking memory. I'm not an Android expert though.

I'd recommend you to create a method in `Obstacle` like `recycle` or something along this way. Then every time you remove `Obstacle` from `obstacles` in `ObstacleManager` call that method. In that method you should aim to recycle all no longer used bitmaps. I'd do it by calling either `Animation#recycle` on every of your animations or calling `AnimationManagerObstacle#recycle`. (`Animation#recycle` would be meant to call `recycle` on every one of your `frames`.)

Comment: thank you! ill give this some thought and let my noob mind to coding process and figure this out!

Comment: @Shawnzey No problem. If you encounter any problems feel free to ask

Comment: i mean besides the fact that the obstacles aren't even drawn as spikes there still black squares is a major one of my problems.

Comment: @Shawnzey try not drawing `rectangle` and `rectangle2` in `Obstacle.draw`

Comment: @Shawnzey are you sure your scaleRect method is working properly?

Comment: it worked for my player but maybe not. i commented out where i call the method and nothing changed really. my only guess is that it's drawing the bitmaps off the screen where the obstacles spawn and there just not moving with the obstacles...